# Tensorflow Nvidia GPU not detected

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

Hi I'm struggling to get Tensorflow V2.11 to find my eGPU (RTX 3060 Ti)

I am currently on Windows 11
CUDA version is 12
I am currently downloading CUDA 11 as well as CUDnn as I've heard it is recommended

I have tried the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

which outputs:

> []

any help would be great

Comment: What does `tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()` return?

Comment: Its getting more interesting, I heard 2.11 is incompatible with gpus on windows so downgraded to 2.10, and running that command I get True, however importing the library tells me that it cannot find the cuda dll's currently trying to figure out where its looking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tensorflow 2.11` is not supporting GPU on Windows machine. `TensorFlow 2.10` was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. So you can try by installing `Tensorflow 2.10` for the GPU setup.

Also you need to install the specific version of CUDA and cuDNN for GPU support in your system which is `CUDA 11.2` and cuDNN `8.1` for Tensorflow 2.10(Tensorflow>=2.5).

Please check the Hardware/Software [requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#hardware_requirements) as mentioned in the link and set the [path](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#set_your_path) to the bin directory after installing these software.

Now follow the `step by step instructions` mentioned in the same link and verify the GPU setup using below code.

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

Comment: Yep, discovered this, I was struggling to get 2.10 to find the CUDA dlls but I think i did something that has made it work now